# How to assign a bound object function to another object property?

Tags: javascript

I tried to bind a function from an object to some variable without external calling bind():

```
var man = {
  age: "22",
  getAge: function(){
    return "My age is "+this.age;
  },
  test: function(){
    return this.getAge.bind(this);
  }
}
```

This works:

```
var a = man.test();
a();
// "My age is 22"
```

But when I try to change some things in my code:

```
var man = {
  age: "22",
  getAge: function(){
    return "My age is "+this.age;
  },
  test: function(){
    return this.getAge.bind(this);
  }()//there it's, that do not do "var a = man.test()", but "var a = man.test"
}
```

JavaScript gives me an Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined(…)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really trying to do.  If you want a plain property access to act like a function call, then you can use a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: No, i just want to write "var a = man.test", without calling like "var a = man.test()"

Comment: Then, `.test` is either a static property asignment or you use a getter like I mentioned in my previous comment.  Those are your two choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `this` is referring to the context the Object literal is written in, not the Object literal.

You can't actually refer to yourself in an *Object literal's* construction time because even it's identifier hasn't been properly set yet. Instead, separate it into two steps

```
// 1, set up with a literal
var man = {
    age: "22",
    getAge: function () {
          return "My age is " + this.age;
    }
}
// 2, set up things needing references to the object we just made
man.test = man.getAge.bind(man);
```

---

By your specific example it looks like you may repeat this pattern many times, are you sure that it wouldn't be better to use a *Constructor*? This also means you can use inheritance and prototyping

For example, you could have *Man* set up as inheriting from *Human*, and also create a *Woman* later with shared code

```
// Common category
function Human(age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.test = this.getAge.bind(this);
}
Human.prototype = Object.create(null);
Human.prototype.getAge = function () {
    return 'My age is ' + this.age;
};

// specific category
function Man(age) {
    Human.call(this, age);
}
Man.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Man.prototype.gender = function () {
    return 'I am male.';
};

// then
var man = new Man('22'); // as you used a string age
var a = man.test;
a(); // "My age is 22"
```

Then later

```
// another specific category
function Woman(age) {
    Human.call(this, age);
}
Woman.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Woman.prototype.gender = function () {
    return 'I am female.';
};

// then usage
var woman = new Woman('22'); // as you used a string age
woman.getAge(); // "22", because getAge was common to humans
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your second version is not referring to what you think it is, it's referring to the window and so does not have the property available...

NB: Adding the `()` to the end calls the anonymous function you created

Comment: It doesn't have to be `window` , but yeah, it's referring to the context the _Object literal_ is written in, not the _Object literal_

Comment: @Paul S. +1  I made an assumption that it was referring to window :-/